# subdomain.domain.com works, but still accessible via domain.com/site

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, redirect, url

I've got a site installed at, for argument's sake, `/var/www/site`, and have a subdomain set up so that it can be accessed via `subdomain.domain.com`.

How do I stop it also being accessed via `domain.com/site`? This obviously works as it is a subdirectory in the root htmldir of `/var/www`.

Will Google currently see this as two different sites, too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a rewrite rule to make sure the content is only accessed through the subdomain. Create a `.htaccess` file in the `site` directory that you want to work only through it's subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

As for the Google question, Google generally sees subdomains as separate sites as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. What I meant about the Google thing was, will it see subdomain.domain.com and domain.com/site as two entities?

Comment: For some reason, doing this stops me from accessing it at all. I obviously changed the url to reflect mine, but I get permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the google thing, your site will be penalized for SEO ranking as google will see it as two different entity and will negative rank your site.

Also, I am not even sure why you are running the other domain from the same document root. The best solution what I will say is to move it out of main site's document root and create a new document root somewhere else, and update your virtual host settings. I don't see a good reason here to even mess with the rewrite rule, when you don't need it at all (Unless there is some specific reason why you did it which I am missing and would like to understand).

Comment: So, the best bet is to create a new dir called 'sites' for example, and keep everything in its own dir in there? That would obviously keep everything separate.

Comment: Yes, that's the best practice, I will say.